# Wcf 3.5 - Different endpoints with different bindings and SOAP

Tags: wcf, soap

I have a problem... I explored whole internet and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Problem: WCF web service, .Net Framework 3.5, 2 different type of clients (Handheld device and usual computer)

What I'm trying to do is to create 2 diferent endpoints, one with basicBinding (For SOAP request) and other with wsBinding (for usual computers)

So I go thru web.config and I created 2 different bindings, related with 2 different endpoints:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicBinding" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="23:59:00"
      sendTimeout="23:59:00" messageEncoding="Text" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="DefaultBinding" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="23:59:59"
      sendTimeout="23:59:59">
      <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="01:00:00" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="qtswsdl.QTS_ServiceBehavior"
    name="qtswsdl.QTS_Service">
    <endpoint address="http://host.com/service.svc/ForHh"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicBinding"
      name="handHeldEndPoint" contract="qtswsdl.QTSPort" />
    <endpoint address="http://host.com/service.svc/ForCp"
      binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DefaultBinding"
      name="coProcessorEndPoint" contract="qtswsdl.QTSPort" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="qtswsdl.QTS_ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="2147483647"maxConcurrentSessions="2147483647"
        maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

So when I try to send SOAP messages to "http://host.com/service.svc/ForHh" Im getting a "HTTP 400 - Bad Request" (the /ForCp is also not working)

I tried with custom clients, with WcfTestClient.exe and I was not able to fin what is happening

Any tip or suggestion?

Thanks for your time

EDIT:

After enable Svc trace I got a couple of exceptions:

```
<Message>The message with Action 'http://Host.com/Service.svc/ForHh' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).</Message>
```

Funny thing is that I'm sending the SOAP request programatically. It's my understanding that if I'm sending SOAP request programatically i don't need to define any contract because it is being send using SOAP 1.1 by default.

Code that sends the request is the following code:

```
private string SendRequestAndGetAnswerFromWebService(string methodName, string requestXml){

     StringBuilder soapRequest = new StringBuilder("<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"");
                soapRequest.Append(" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" ");
                soapRequest.Append("xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body>");
                soapRequest.Append(requestXml);//Body
                soapRequest.Append("</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>");

                   WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(@"http://Host.com/Service.svc/" + methodName);
                   HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)webRequest;
                   httpRequest.Method = "POST";
                   httpRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=ascii";
                   httpRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction: " + @"http://Host.com/Service.svc/Service.svc/" + methodName);
                   httpRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
                   httpRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                   httpRequest.Timeout = 7000;
                   httpRequest.ContentLength = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(soapRequest.ToString());
                   Stream requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();

                   //Create Stream and send Request 
                   StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream, Encoding.ASCII);
                   streamWriter.Write(soapRequest.ToString());
                   //Send the request             
                   streamWriter.Close();

                   //Get the Response
                   HttpWebResponse wr = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
                   StreamReader srd = new StreamReader(wr.GetResponseStream());
                   string resulXmlFromWebService = srd.ReadToEnd();
                   return resulXmlFromWebService;
}
```

Maybe my assumption about contract and soap messages sent programatically are wrong...

Comment: turn on wcf trace and get the exact error: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madhuponduru/archive/2006/05/18/601458.aspx

Comment: the soapation header seems to be wrong. you can see the correct one in the wsdl.

Comment: Yes, sorry in the "real" code it's the correct one. Was my fault because I want to "hide" the real url. You can trust on that. Regarding send SOAP requests programatically... my assumption is correct? I mean, I don't need any contract on the client side. Thanks for your time Yaron

Comment: I suggest for now you focus on using the wcf test client. maybe create some new service just to check that works, and then compare the working service config to yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, this is very bad practice -- you should NOT be manually authoring SOAP requests to WCF services this way. It is better if you were to take advantage of the out-of-the-box WCF request/reply paradigms instead of resorting to setting up headers manually.

What I would recommend is to create an alternative example where you DO achieve the same thing out-of-the-box (with perhaps DataContracts, OperationContracts, and ServiceContracts on the client-end, perhaps taking advantage of WebHttpBehavior and WebHttpBinding). Examine the exact messages that are sent and received in that scenario, and closely examine, character by character, how those messages are different from the ones you're sending here.

Also, it's hard to tell what else you could be doing wrong from just the detail you've provided.

Here is what I suggest:

- Enable tracing on the service side, generate tracing logs, and analyze with SvcTraceViewer. To do this, follow the instructions at [this MSDN article on using the service trace viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx). Notice what's different between the first and second time.
- Turn on debug exceptions. This is done by turning in includeExceptionDetailInFaults, which [you can do by following the instructions here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/david_bennett/archive/2006/11/12/how-to-turn-on-debug-exceptions-with-wcf.aspx). Notice what's different between the first and second time.
- Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to monitor the wire traffic on both the client side and the service side.

Generally, once you do this, you should plenty of more info on what's going funky at the service side and can diagnose the issue pretty quickly. Try it, and please report back! :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Let's try it

Comment: Sorry for delay. Your suggestions allowed me to notice the real problem. The soap message didn't have needed values.